# How do I enable Platform Builder mode in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, smartphone, platform-builder

After installing VS2008, the platform builder mod, and the WM7 aku, VS usually prompts you, upon first startup, for your default mode. If you make a mistake and select something other than PB7, how do you get back into PB mode?

I can get the device window, but it is always greyed out. I can also configure my normal connection settings, but VS will never connect to the device.

I have other machines, where I did select the default option correctly. They work just fine.

I'm hoping I do not have to reinstall everything.

namaste,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Tool menu and select "Import and Export Settings..." option. Then select "Reset all settings" in the Wizard. On the next screen you can save current settings. Then on the final screen, it should allow you to select which collection of settings you want to use. I don't have platform builder but hopefully that option should show up there.

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Import and Export Settings...
X Reset All Settings
(Save or don't save)
Select new Setting.